# How to read error details from REST API

Tags: java, android, http, curl, httpresponse

I am trying to register a user to my Web Server. If i send valid details to the server then i get 201 code in response which stands for "created". But when i send wrong credentials to the server i.e same username as before then i get 400 FileNotFoundException. I need to interpret error details not only 400 code. Because if i send wrong details using curl from command line then i get error details also e.g this username already exists. 
Here is my code to read response from the server. Actually i've tried two different methods but they all end up in same error which is 400(Bad Request) nothing else.

```
    public static String readResponse(HttpURLConnection connection)
        throws IOException, JSONException {

    InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line;
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
        response.append('\r');
    }
    return response.toString();
}

public static String readResponseFromServer(HttpURLConnection connection) throws IOException {
    BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader
            (connection.getInputStream()));
    String line = "";
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
        stringBuilder.append(line).append("\n");
    }
    return stringBuilder.toString();
}
```

In the above code there are two methods for reading response from the server.

And here is how i am using these methods to read response from the server

```
System.out.println("Server Response" + WebServiceHelpers.readResponseFromServer(urlConnection));
```

And i am also using the 2nd method which is **readResponse()** from the above code.

And here is the screenshot of curl command in which i am sending wrong details to the server and getting error details.

[image: Server Response using curl]

I've also tried this with HTTPIE and i am also getting the same response as using curl command i.e **A user with that username already exists.**

I need these error details in my Java code also. I have searched the internet but didn't found a solution.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public static String readResponse(HttpURLConnection connection)
    throws IOException, JSONException {
    int respCode = connection.getResponseCode();

    InputStream is = null;
    if (isErrorCode(respCode)) {
        is = connection.getErrorStream();
    } else if (connection.getErrorStream() != null) {
        is = connection.getInputStream();
    }
    //FIXME: InputStreamReader must be constructed with right charset
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
    String line;
    StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();
    while((line = rd.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(line);
    }
    return response.toString();
}
```

Write isErrorCode method. It should interpret response code 400 as error and other codes as you need. Also notice fixme comment. When you are constructing InputStreamReader without a charset it uses default charset (UTF-8 if you don't provide *file.encoding* property) but correct way is to get charset from Content-Type response header and process response body with that encoding. Method for extracting charset from response may looks like this

```
private String getCharset(HttpURLConnection con) { 
    String charset = "";

    String contentType = con.getContentType();
    if (contentType != null) {
        String[] values = contentType.split(";");
        for (String value : values) {
            String trimValue = value.trim();

            if (trimValue.toLowerCase().startsWith("charset=")) {
                charset = trimValue.substring("charset=".length());
            }
        }
    }
    if ("".equals(charset)) {
        charset = "UTF-8";
    }

    return charset;
}
```